# Assigning an int using the ternary conditional operator and the values of two other ints

Tags: c, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

In the Big Nerd Ranch C book, which I'm using to learn C, it is said that "whenever you have a scenario where a value is assigned to a variable based on a conditional, you have a candidate for the 'conditional/ternary operator', which is ?."

So my questions is, can someone explain to me the following code snippet:

```
int i = 20;
int j = 25;
int k = (i > j) ? 10 : 5;

if (5 < j - k) {
    //First expression
    printf("the first expression is true.");
} else if ( j > i ) {
    //Second Expression 
    printf("The second expression is true.");
} else {
    printf("Neither expression is true.");
}
```

Comment: `k` is equal to 5, and it won't compile because the `else if` line doesn't have any condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int k = (i > j) ? 10 : 5;` in your example is equivalent to:

```
if (i > j)
{
    int k = 10;
}
else
{
    int k = 5;
}
```

The ternary operator is just a shortcut for special cases of if-conditionals when assigning a value based on a condition.

The rest of the snippet is not that hard to understand, if remove the incomplete `else if` snippet:

```
if (5 < j(25) - k(5)) == if (5 < 20)
{
    printf("the expression is true.");
}
else
{
     printf("the expression is false.");
}
```

Because `5` is smaller than `25 - 5 = 20`, This program will print "the first expression is true".